# Does a black holes destorys every information...?

Tags: black-holes, information

,...or does it mix all those atoms in a way that we cannot know what information those atoms formed? When we would know how each atom was before and how it was placed, before it entered the black-hole, could we restore the information after the black hole is evaporated?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox